# Scripting-Search Multiple Strings

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, grep

I have a script (./lookup) that will search a file ($c). The file will contain a list of cities. What I would like to do be able to search the file for what the user enters as an argument (./lookup Miami). For example; I can make the script return what I want if it is a single word city (Miami), but I can't figure out a way to make it work for 2 or more words (Los Angeles).  I can get the single strings to return what I want with the following.

```
grep $1 $c
```

I was thinking about a loop, but I am not sure on how to do that as I am new to scripting and Linux. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever arguments could possibly contain spaces, proper quoting is essential in Bash:

```
grep "$1" "$c"
```

The user will need to say `./lookup "Los Angeles"`.  If you don't like that, you can try:

```
grep "$*" "$c"
```

Then all arguments to the script will be passed together as one string to grep.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes sense. I was under the impression that by quoting $*, it would take it literally. Thanks for the solution!